# Problem with Min and Max

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

**s=min{max{0,a}, max{0,b}, 1/(1-a) max{0,1-a}}**

is there any alternative way to make this more concise without condition and in one expression.

Condition is -infty<a<infty and -infty<b<1

Comment: how about `Min[Ramp[{a, b, 1 - b}]/{1, 1, 1 - b}]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use that $min(x,y,z)=min(y,min(x,z))$. Let us do the first part

```
FullSimplify[Min[Max[0, a], 1/(1 - a) Max[0, 1 - a]]]
(*0 < a < 1*)
```

Now the rest. The function is zero unless $0\le a\le1$ and $0\le b\le1$:

```
FullSimplify[Min[Max[0, a], Max[0, b], 1/(1 - a) Max[0, 1 - a]], 
 Assumptions -> 1 > a > 0 && 1 > b > 0]
(* Min[a,b] *)
```

The final answer can be written as

```
UnitBox[a - 1/2, b - 1/2] * Min[a, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming[Element[a | b, Reals] && b < 1,
  Min[Max[0, a], Max[0, b], 1/(1 - a) Max[0, 1 - a]] // FullSimplify]
```

$$
\begin{cases}
 a & a>0\land a\leq b \\
 b & a<1\land b>0\land a>b \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Roman. But I want to have a single expression using min and max function and not want to write in conditional form.

Answer (score 0):

```
PiecewiseExpand[Min[Max[0, a], Max[0, b], 1/(1 - a)*Max[0, 1 - a]]]
```

$$\begin{cases}
 a & 0<a<1\land a-b\leq 0\land b>0 \\
 b & 0<a<1\land 0<b<1\land a-b>0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks @user64494. But I want to have a single expression using min and max function and not want to write in this  Piecewise form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a*Boole[0<a<=b]+b*Boole[0<b<a<1]
```

If this is not acceptable then please show an acceptable form of an expression which has a value of `a` when `0<a<=b` and a value of `0` otherwise. A list of functions which are not acceptable to use would be very helpful. A list of functions which are acceptable to use would be very helpful. Thank you.

Quick approximate test

```
Union[
  Table[a=RandomReal[{-10,10}];b=RandomReal[{-10,1}];
    a*Boole[0<a<=b]+b*Boole[0<b<a<1] == Min[Max[0,a],Max[0,b],1/(1-a)Max[0,1-a]],
   {10000}]]
```

returns

```
{True}
```